# PHP :mbstring module install

Tags: centos, centos6, php, mbstring

I have tried to install the mbstring module for PHP. I have entered the below commands:

```
yum install php-mbstring
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl restart
```

Module is now installed but the errors has not dissapeared.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_send_mail()
```

In my phpinfo(), "mbstring" doesn't exist...

OS: centos 6
PHP: 5.3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you install PHP on your system? The PHP version currently supported via YUM install is 5.3.3, but you said your PHP version is 5.3.8 which leads me to believe that you may have compiled PHP manually. If so, you will have to recompile with the `--enable-mbstring` flag.

Comment: you are right... I forgot this "detail" :-) I will try to recompile it now ~ Thank you

Comment: No problem. Make sure you type `make clean` before you attempt to `make`, otherwise your new configure will not be used.

Comment: Perfectly (sorry for the delay)